# How to sequentially execute async functions in dart with WebSocket

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, stream

I am current writing a WebSocket client. There are a few functions that I need to happen sequentially.

currently I do it in this way

1. Connect to server
2. Then set up a listener.
3. Add Conditional statement to listener.(To check if response id's match request ids)
4. send request One with id
5. if response id matches request One Id then process request
6. send request Two
7. repeat

This makes sequential actions look something like this

```
_channel.stream.listen((response) {
   if(response.id == requestOne.id) {
      handleRequestOneResponse(response);
   }

   if (response.id == requestTwo.id){
      handleRequestTwoResponse(response);
   }
   ...
});

sendActionOneRequest();

handleRequestOneResponse() {
   // Some processing
   sendActionTwoRequest();
}

handleRequestTwoResponse() {
   // some processing

   sendActionThreeRequest();
}
```

What I want to do is

Set up an async function
Send the request to the WebSocket server.
Pause the execution of the async function.
wait until a matching response comes from the server
complete the async function.

This would allow me to write a series of actions like

```
await actionOne();
await actionTwo();
await actionThree();
```

I'm thinking I can set up and destroy a stream listener in each `action` function but I don't know how to wait for a specific response before exiting.

On the other hand I think I can even use the existing listener on the outside, but I still can't figure out to wait till a specific response comes in before moving forward.

As it is I have to jump through every function to find out what comes after the other and there are more than 5 requests that have to be sent sequentially.

Comment: check [StreamQueue](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/pkg.async/StreamQueue-class.html) - after sending the request you can then wait for a response with `StreamQueue.next`

Comment: Hmm, having a hard time seeing how it would solve my problem. I'll spend some more time trying to wrap my head around it

Comment: Thanks for your replies I ended up using await for in this case. But I’m reading about the streamqueue to see if I can understand it. With Await for I can get any number of responses and only respond to the one I’m looking for. Streamqueue seems like it would require a lot more work to get the responses

Comment: I ended up doing this. 
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pnJDmhP5ZJ/

I think your solution would let me abandon the `await for ` loop after some time if no matching response Is received. But I have to work with this for now. Post an answer and I'll upvote it